# Virtual Hard Drive not booting - VMWare

Tags: vmware

I have a .vmdk (VMWare hard disk) file that I cannot use as the lone disk in a new virtual machine.  If I attach it to an existing virtual machine then it works fine.  It has Windows Server 2003 on it.

When I attempt to boot the new VM it attempts a network boot. I am using VMWare Workstation 6.5.

I could not find a PXE option in the settings, and I did look in the VM config file for "PXE" but did not find one.

Comment: look at the settings for the guest sounds like you have pxe enabled. Its not the disk its the config for the guest.

Comment: how can i change that?

Comment: fraid to ask, what version of "vmware" do you have?

Comment: I could not find a PXE option in the settings, and I did look in the VM config file for "PXE" but did not find one.

Comment: What is your objective? To boot from the virtual drive or to boot from the network? Please make your ultimate goal clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the options depends on what VMWare product you are using.  Often times, I just edit the configuration files by hand.  They are plain text and you can see options that aren't "available" in some products.  Just keep a backup for reference.

Comment: I could not find a PXE option in the settings, and I did look in the VM config file for "PXE" but did not find one.

Comment: Thats in the "virtual BIOS".  I'm answering this at work so I don't have access to my copy of VMWare, but I seem to recall that in the menus somewhere you can break in the BIOS at boot.  From there, you should be able to change the PXE option.  When you first create a VM that is generic/uninstalled the conf files have a setting that leaves the bios screen up longer I belive.